# Accessing members of generic struct in C++ gives error

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I am a complete beginner to C++ coming from C. I wrote this code as a part of a simple database application:

```
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T>
struct entry {
  uint64_t ID;
  T data;
};

template <typename T>
uint64_t calculate_offset(entry<T> thing) {
  return sizeof(uint64_t) * entry<T>.ID;
}
```

I'd like to access `entry.ID` without having to know the type of `entry.data`. When I try to compile my code clang gives me the following error:

```
totes.cpp:11:48: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
```

How do I achieve the desired behavior? What does this error mean?

Comment: return sizeof(uint64_t) * thing.ID;

Comment: Well this is awkward.

Comment: Should I delete this question or keep it up?

Comment: @hiy, I'd suggest deleting it. I VTC it.

Comment: `Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
entry<T> thing
// entry<T> is the type
// thing is the name of an instance of the type
```

To access member state of a class or struct you do so through an instance of the object. For example:

```
thing.ID;
```